# How to accurately measure svg text height

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to fairly accurately determine the height of the height of the text in my svg elements, unfortunately everything i try to use bounding box and the height i get from this, it's always returns a height that is too big at bigger fonts.

Is there a way to get a more accurate measurement of text height one that is more dependent on the text within my elements.

Comment: are you interested in the height of the text element (as stated in the OP and which usually gives higher values than the height of actual characters, so you are getting correct results) or height of actual rendered characters/text?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() for browser coords. For svg coords, getBBox()

Comment: @JanStránský i am interested in the height of the rendered characters / text, i have edited my post above to make this clear

Comment: @Dom i am after the height of the rendered text, getbbox will not give me this value

Comment: I do not know any way measuring actual SVG glyphs in javascript. There are alternatives, e.g. using Canvas and [TextMetrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) or [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/)

Comment: @JanStránský TextMetrics doesn't seem to have a text height function but i am amusing this can be calculated using some of the other functions it has ? do you know of any resources you could direct me to that may allow me to figure out how to do this with TextMetrics or opentype ?

Comment: no, sorry. I was just searching similar problem and came to these. But since I had to support also IE11 (which does not support much TextMetrics) and opentype was an overkill, I do not have real experience. Maybe you can ask another question(s) if you are interested.